# How do I print the song titles next to the link?

Tags: python, api, python-3.x, spotify

I'm working on a music repository using spotify, and one of the last things I have to do is to get the song title to appear next to its link, and I am not sure how I go about doing this.

```
def makeRequestToSpotify(songname):

    encodedname = urllib.parse.quote_plus(songname)

    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=" + encodedname+ "&type=track"

    content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

    data = json.loads(content.readall().decode('utf-8'))

    songLink = data["tracks"]["items"][0]["external_urls"]["spotify"]

    #print(songLink,"\n")
    link = songLink
    song = getMusicFilesFromFolder()


def getMusicFilesFromFolder(afolder):

    extensions = [".mp3",".wma",".aac",".m4a"]

    filenames = []
    for x in os.walk(afolder):
        for file in x[2]:
            file_name, filext = os.path.splitext(file)
            for ext in extensions:
                if filext == ext:
                    filenames.append(file_name)
                    break

    for file in filenames:

        makeRequestToSpotify(file)

    return filenames
```

The make request to spotify function gets me the links, and the the get music files from folder function gets list of the song names.

How do I go about getting the song name next to the corresponding link?